# Reshape to wide format with a time column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, reshape2

This I am certain is a duplicate question. Pardon me for this violation.  I have a dataset like this in a long format.

```
   ID TIME  Col1   Value 
   A    1   X1     25
   B    1   X1     26
   C    1   X2     27
   A    2   X1     28
   A    2   X2     29
   C    2   X1     30
   D    1   X1     31
   D    1   X2     32
   C    3   X2     33
```

What I am trying to do is convert this to a wide format like this

```
  ID TIME   X1  X2
  A  1      25  
  B  1      26  
  C  1          27
  A  2      28  29
  C  2      30  
  D  1      31  32
  C  3          33
```

I tried `df1 %>% spread(Col1, Value)` and this did not work. Any help on transforming this to wide format is much apricated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Col1, values_from = Value)`

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, Ritche,  that was perfect. Thanks.